# Native Android UI on Hybrid Application

Tags: android, android-layout, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to display native android datepicker in an IBM MobileFirst Platform-based Hybrid Application.

I followed the below tutorial but datepicker is not getting displayed when I click on the textbox.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-ui-elements-hybrid-applications/

The following is my test application: https://db.tt/tm8ihJc9

The following is the code in js file when textbox is clicked

```
$('#textDate').on('click', function(){
      $('#errorMsg').empty();

    WL.App.sendActionToNative("setMyDate");

      WL.App.addActionReceiver("myActionReceiver", function actionReceiver(received){
            if(received.action == 'setMyDate'){
                alert(received);
                $('#errorMsg').html(received.data.errorReason);
            }
      });

 });
```

In Java code, I created one class textboxDate that contain code for ActionReceiver

```
public class textboxDate extends CordovaActivity implements WLActionReceiver{
private Activity parentActivity;
DatePicker datePicker;
int hour, minute;

TextView textVw;

public textboxDate(Activity pActivity){
    parentActivity = pActivity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.textdate);

    WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(new textboxDate(this));

    super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());

    try{
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("setMyDate", 12345);
    WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("setMyDate", data);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

}

@Override
public void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject data) {
    if (action.equals("setMyDate" )){
        WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(this);
        showDatePicker();
    } 

}

public void showDatePicker(){

    textVw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        textVw.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WL.getInstance().removeActionReceiver(this);
}
```

}

Comment: You should post some code of what you are doing, we can't figure it out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addActionReceiver` must be placed in the main activity's `onCreate` method, and not in the class that implements the `WLActionReceiver`, and certainly not in the `onActionReceived` method.

You are also incorrectly handling the way you are returning the value from the datePicker to the WebView...
In fact, all of the implementation is incorrect. :/

For whatever you are trying to achieve here, it sounds like you may want to opt to use [WL.NativePage](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/android-using-native-pages-hybrid-applications/) instead.

Here is the same project, implemented using `WL.NativePage`. Take a look at common\js\main.js and android\nativeResources\src\com\getDatePicker\DatePickerActivity.java

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvhlo684ulpb40c/getDateProject.zip

Comment: I have one sign up page in hybrid application that contains various textbox. Out of that page, one textbox contains date information. When I click on Enter date textbox, I want to open Native android datepicker to select the date and return the selected date to the sign up page(WebView). I just want to use one native UI element datepicker in the hybrid application.

Comment: Then this is **exactly** what my sample is doing. You should incorporate it into your app. You can adjust what you are getting back from the date picker in the native code.

Comment: Okay. But in your project, when I click on the link "Click to select a date", native datepicker is not getting open on device.

Comment: Hmm, I tested in a simulator for Android 4.4.2 and it worked. I guess some tweaks will be needed, but the code is sound and to use - the javascript and java. I don't know what error you're getting...

Comment: The following is the error :   Uncaught Error: A native page is already loaded. Cannot call another native page. worklight.js:15435
show worklight.js:15435
selectDate main.js:8
onclick index.html:38

Comment: @user3654246, You're right - I placed the .java file in the wrong folder in the nativeResources folder as well as forgot in the .zip several other files. I've updated both the answer and the project. Re-download.

Comment: Great. If this satisfies you, please mark as Answered.